# Vertex Arrays keep crashing

Tags: c++, sfml

I recently started coding with SFML 2.3, I had success drawing shape and circles, but with vertices all progams I make keep crashing

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/OpenGL.hpp>

using namespace sf;

const int widht = 800, height = 600;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    RenderWindow app(VideoMode(widht, height), "SFML APP");
    Event event;
    VertexArray vArray;
    vArray.setPrimitiveType(PrimitiveType::Quads);
    while (app.isOpen())
    {
        while (app.pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
            case Event::Closed:
                app.close();
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < widht; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                vArray[0].position = Vector2f(i * 10, j * 10);
                vArray[1].position = Vector2f(i * 10 + 10, j * 10);
                vArray[2].position = Vector2f(i * 10 + 10, j * 10 + 10);
                vArray[3].position = Vector2f(i * 10, j * 10 + 10);
            }
            app.draw(vArray);
        }
        app.clear();
        app.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why does it crash?

Comment: So which line did it crash on?  By not giving us even this little bit of information, you're going to get downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you can't simply say `vArray[index].position = <something>;`, like you do in your loop, because you never allocate enough memory. In short, there are *no elements in `vArray`*.

You have to allocate this memory somehow. For example `std::vector<int> tmp(4);` pre-allocates memory for 4 members of type `int`.

---

In your case, following the [documentation](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1VertexArray.php#abf85f4baff4c282e2d07ea97b5913aad), you can do this:

```
VertexArray vArray(PrimitiveType::Quads, 4);
```

Here you're allocating memory for four instances of `PrimitiveType::Quads`, which is exactly what you need.